# Basic SPARQL query to return triples with label that contains string in Blazegraph

Tags: sparql, blazegraph

I am trying the following SPARQL query:

```
SELECT ?uri ?label
WHERE {
    ?uri rdfs:label "Weblex"@en .
    ?uri rdfs:label ?label
}
```

However, I get a cryptic error message:

```
ERROR: SPARQL-QUERY: queryStr=SELECT ?uri ?label
WHERE {
    ?uri rdfs:label "Weblex"@en .
    ?uri rdfs:label ?label
}
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to read data: 
com.bigdata.rwstore.PhysicalAddressResolutionException: Address did not resolve to physical address: -118579
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
```

The query looks like it's valid so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: it's unclear where you got this error. At least on Wikidata which is deployed on Blazegraph your query works fine resp. does not lead to an error. So, nobody knows your setup, how you loaded which dataset, and so on and so forth